# Change cell height on cell tap using RxSwift

Tags: ios11, swift4, rx-swift

I am using RxSwift in my app to populate the tableview. Currently data is being shown successfully. Now I want to change the cell height on cell tap.. this is I am doing on cell tap.

```
       _ = dataTable.rx.itemSelected
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] indexPath in
//                let cell = self?.dataTable.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TradebookMyRequestCell

                if (self?.btnMyRequest.isSelected)!{
                    print("index Path \(Int(indexPath.row)) =")
                    if self?.selectedCellIndexPath != nil && self?.selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
                        //                selectedCellIndexPath = nil
                        self?.cellTapped = true
                    } else {
                        self?.selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
                        self?.cellTapped = false
                    }

                    self?.dataTable.beginUpdates()

                    let selectedRowIndex = indexPath
                    self?.currentRow = selectedRowIndex.row
                    if !(self?.indexPaths.contains((self?.selectedCellIndexPath!)!))!{
                        self?.indexPaths.append((self?.selectedCellIndexPath!)!)
                    }
                    else {
                        let index = self?.indexPaths.index(of: (self?.selectedCellIndexPath!)!)
                        self?.indexPaths.remove(at: index!)
                    }
                    self?.dataTable.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                    self?.dataTable.endUpdates()
                }
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This is code for height change of cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        // cell = nil.
                if btnMyRequest.isSelected  {
                 if indexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
                    cellTapped = true
                        return 120
                    }
                    else {
                    cellTapped = false
                        return 70
                    }
                }else{
                    return 76
                }

    }
```

The problem is when I tap the cell, first heightforrow method is called then my cell tap action gets triggered. Since I am new to rx can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to deal with this aswel. My solution was as follows; Add a "isExpanded" property to your item and toggle that whenever the user clicks on a cell.

```
tableView.rx.itemSelected.subscribe(onNext: toggleCell).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The `toggleCell` function looks like this

```
func toggleCell(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    let element = dataSource[indexPath]
    element.isExpanded = !element.isExpanded
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

The UITableView's delegate looks like this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let item = dataSource[indexPath]
    if item.isExpanded {
        return 144
    }
    return 44
}
```

I hope this helps you.